# Choose which compiler to use when compiling individual files in the Shared Project?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, shared-project

I have one Windows project, a Linux project and a Shared Project referenced by both the first two projects.

I've set up everything necessary to build the Linux project with a Remote Debugger. Now when I try to compile a file individually in the Shared Project (Ctrl+F7), it defaults to trying to compile it with the remote compiler. Is there any way to choose which compiler to use when compiling individual files in the Shared Project?

Comment: I think it follows whatever you've set as the start-up project (right-click on project in solution explorer for menu).

Comment: @stanthomas Thanks. That made the default "Build and Run" button in the toolbar default to the the compiler of the start-up project. But Ctrl-F7 still defaults to using the remote compiler.